# Content Assist fails for Ruby with Aptana on Eclipse

Tags: ruby, eclipse, aptana, content-assist, code-assist

I've a clean install of Aptana as an Eclipse plug-in (fresh installation).

My suspicion that this could be a duplicate key-binding (quite possibly a bug), but information online is sparse.

- Eclipse: 3.5.2-8ubuntu3
- Aptana: 3.0.5.201110061700-7
- Ubuntu: 11.04, kernel 2.6.38-11-generic

Session data:

- eclipse.buildId=M20100211-1343
- java.version=1.6.0_22
- java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
- BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_NZ
- Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64

For Python scripts this generally seems OK (for now).
I'm starting on a new Ruby script, define an object followed by a "." & try to invoke Content Assist via the ctrl+space keystroke & presented with the following pop-up error:

> "Content Assist" did not complete normally. Please see the log for more information.

and

> model is already installed

this the stack trace provided:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: model is already installed
at org.eclipse.jface.text.link.LinkedModeModel.addGroup(LinkedModeModel.java:413)
at com.aptana.editor.common.scripting.snippets.SnippetTemplateProposal.doApply(SnippetTemplateProposal.java:277)
at com.aptana.editor.common.scripting.snippets.SnippetTemplateProposal.apply(SnippetTemplateProposal.java:123)
at com.aptana.editor.common.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.insertProposal(CompletionProposalPopup.java:912)
at com.aptana.editor.common.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.completeCommonPrefix(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1915)
at com.aptana.editor.common.contentassist.CompletionProposalPopup.incrementalComplete(CompletionProposalPopup.java:1829)
at com.aptana.editor.common.contentassist.ContentAssistant.showPossibleCompletions(ContentAssistant.java:1992)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.SourceViewer.doOperation(SourceViewer.java:835)
at org.eclipse.jface.text.source.projection.ProjectionViewer.doOperation(ProjectionViewer.java:1533)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction$1.run(ContentAssistAction.java:82)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.ContentAssistAction.run(ContentAssistAction.java:80)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
at org.eclipse.ui.commands.ActionHandler.execute(ActionHandler.java:185)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.LegacyHandlerWrapper.execute(LegacyHandlerWrapper.java:109)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.executeCommand(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:470)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.press(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:824)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.processKeyEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:880)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.filterKeySequenceBindings(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:569)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard.access$3(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:510)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.keys.WorkbenchKeyboard$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(WorkbenchKeyboard.java:125)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1175)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1200)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1185)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1212)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.gtk_key_press_event(Widget.java:706)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_key_press_event(Control.java:2837)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_key_press_event(Composite.java:703)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:1570)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4594)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4191)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:7603)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1185)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:1860)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3110)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2405)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2369)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2221)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:500)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:493)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:194)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:368)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:559)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:514)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1311)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1287)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with Studio 3.0.5: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3390.  It has been fixed for the next 3.0.6, or you could update to the beta stream using [the instructions here](http://aptana.com/r/apupdate).